# Why val() is not returning the value of <button value="value">?

Tags: jquery

I read that val() returns value of input element but here in my code it is not working.
What

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $("button").val();
    alert(a)
});
</script>
```

```html
<button value="text"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you never use `a` you just have an empty `alert()`

Comment: You have kept va() instead of val()

Comment: So many problems here - every line is wrong. `var a = $("button").va();` must be `var a = $("button").val();`. `alert()` is useless, you're not telling it what to output. `<button value="text"/>` cannot be self-closing.

Comment: that was typing mistake. I have corrected the question. sorry about that and please don't down vote. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use button element and call .html()

```html
<button> value </button>
```

or use input element and call .val()

```html
<input type="button" value="value"/>
```

Then access them as

```
// jquery
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var btn = $("button").html();
    var inp = $("input").va();
    alert('button: '+btn) 
    alert('input: '+inp)
});
</script>

//html
<button>value1</button>
<input type="button" value="value2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**the most possible reason is, there must be additional button elements**.
but, here, in your question, you have given only one button.
best way of using jQuery is giving id / class to each element, you want to operate/access.
in your example, give id as such and check the result.

```
<button id="uniqueIdNotGivenToAnotherElement" value="text"/>
```

**(note that same "class" can be given to multiple elements, but to operate them, another method is used)**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $("#uniqueIdNotGivenToAnotherElement").val();
    alert(a);
});
</script>
```

Comment: @charlietfl gave a thought on what had happened. and i appologize for my words. i edited my answer. thanks for pointing out my mistake;